# Google App Engine Custom SSL & Android SNI + VIP?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ssl, https, sni

I have an app up and running on GAE, bought my SNI slots, installed the SSL cert and the SSL certificate is working on desktop chrome, safari, firefox, and on all iOS devices fine.

For some reason, Android is returning an error that says "This Certificate isn't from a Trusted Authority", but then it lists COMODO and the details as the CA?

In the Google SSL settings I only have the SNI cert option to serve (i see in tutorials a SNI + VIP I can buy).  I'm wondering if Android does not support SNI, and do I need to buy the SNI + VIP to have SSL work for Android?

It's ironic that it's hosted on GAE, and yet Android is the only platform with issues ;)

Comment: check this link https://github.com/SreenuAndroid/ServerHelper

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly these issue before and it's possible to solve it.

According to:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Look for the word "chained certificate":

"certificate file can contain at most five certificates; this number includes chained and intermediate certificates."

"If the host certificate requires an intermediate or chained certificate (as many Certificate Authorities (CAs) issue), you will need to append the intermediate or chained certificates to the end of the public certificate file."

So what you do is to open up your favorite text editor, and combine all the provided certificate into 1 file and upload to Google. It will then works perfectly in Android.

SNI alone works perfectly fine, so save your $39 per month for VIP.